# Error after using request parameters in function

Tags: node.js, express

I’m getting an error when trying to fetch data with the instagram-node package while using request parameters.

Making the call without parameters but hard coded values works without any errors and gives me the right result.

When I use the parameters, as shown below, I get the following error:

```
{ [Error: Wrong params "lat" & "lng"] retry: [Function] }
```

This is my code:

```
//http://localhost:8080/photos/2000/52.3677985/4.8852246
app.get('/photos/:dist/:longitude/:latitude', function(req,res) {

var dist = req.params.dist;
var longitude = req.params.longitude;
var latitude = req.params.latitude;

console.log(dist + " " + longitude + " " + latitude);

ig.media_search(longitude, latitude, {distance: dist},
  function (err, medias, remaining, limit) {

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {

        res.render('pages/index', {grams: medias});

    }

});
```

Logging the parameters gives me the required values, but they don’t seem to be defined when making the ig.media_search() call.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that I'm seeing is that you're sending in latitude and longitude in backwards. The signature is:

```
media_search = function(lat, lng, options, cb) {}
```

Secondly, this is the line that is throwing your error from instagram-node:

```
if(typeof lat !== 'number' || typeof lng !== 'number') {
    return handle_error(new Error('Wrong params "lat" & "lng"'), cb, retry);
}
```

I'm going to guess that you're sending in string values that have the numbers you want as they were parsed out of the url string. If you try calling it like this, you might see better results:

```
//http://localhost:8080/photos/2000/52.3677985/4.8852246
app.get('/photos/:dist/:longitude/:latitude', function(req,res) {

// Cast as numbers to send into instagram.
var dist = Number(req.params.dist);
var longitude = Number(req.params.longitude);
var latitude = Number(req.params.latitude);

console.log(dist + " " + longitude + " " + latitude);

ig.media_search(latitude, longitude, {distance: dist},
  function (err, medias, remaining, limit) {

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {

        res.render('pages/index', {grams: medias});

    }

});
```

By the way, I've never used this package before. If you go from the [npm page for this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-node) you can find a link to the [github repo](https://github.com/totemstech/instagram-node) for it. If you look at their [package.json](https://github.com/totemstech/instagram-node/blob/master/package.json) you can find a main value that will lead you to the entry point for the package. In that file (lib/instagram.js) you can Ctrl+F for [media_search and find the function in you're calling](https://github.com/totemstech/instagram-node/blob/master/lib/instagram.js#L845). Just thought you might want to know how to go through and debug something like this. :)